# Use a receiptprinter in WinRT over serial port

Tags: c#, serial-port, windows-runtime

i wanna print to a receipt printer. This would be plugged to a RS323 port. Mostly over a USB adapter.

The reason is, that I try to implement a small cashier app. So there would it be fantastic if I can print through a receipt printer device.

So my Question is, is it possible to communicate with this device within a windows store app (WinRT)? Or is that not possible in general?

Comment: No can do.  Distributing such an app through the Store makes little sense.  Write a desktop app instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Serial and parallel ports are not supported in WinRT as can be seen in: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh464945%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)

There is a line in the table describing that there is no WinRT alternative for the serial and parallel port support that existed int the Win32 API.

Best regards

Comment: Okay... than i must use a separate driver to wich i comunicate via webservice or s.th. Thx a lot :)